# Apply name of the SP in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

These SP in the picture below need to be applied in a table and the result would be:

```
Stored procedure  
----------------  
dbo.upsGetBillOfmaterials  
dbo.upsGetWhereUsedProductID  
dbo.uspPrintError  
HumanResources.uspUpdateEmployeeHireInfo
----
----
----
----
```

How should I do it?
The list of the storedprocedure in the map "Programmability" will increase in the future so no no manual input with the name of the stored procedure.

// Fullmetalboy

[image]

Comment: Please don't sign your posts. And can you clarify what you mean? You actually just want to `INSERT` some value like `MyStoredProcedure` into a `varchar` column of a table? Can you show an example or sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with following query:

```
  INSERT INTO table_name(column_proc_name)select name from sys.objects where type='p'
```

Comment: "select name from sys.objects where type='p'" is the right answer

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean 
the currently executing sp you can:

```
select 'I am ' + object_name(@@procid)
```